# VSCode - Is there any option to replace any form of text within single quotes in vs code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a very long sql query

```
update emplyee_table SET name = 'abc',age='25',address='stackoverflow' WHERE id = 10
```

I want the above query to get replaced like this by any vscode operation.

```
update emplyee_table SET name = ?,age=?,address=? WHERE id = 10
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use find and replace in VSCode along with an appropriate RegEx. 
This Regex should work out: `'[^';]*'`

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> will bring up the replace menu - after enabling regex replace (the button looks like `.*`), replace the pattern `'[^';]*'` with `?`. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> will replace all of the matches in the open editor.

Comment: This won't work out well, since you haven't added a negating group. If there are two single quote words in a line, it will select the entire line instead of the two words separately.